# Do I need to host the backend server for Stripe\Braintree payment gateway after I move the app to production?

Tags: stripe-payments, braintree-sandbox

if anyone could give me a clear high level answer that would be great. I want to integrate a payment gateway into my app eg: Strip/Braintree, and I have gotten it all working to the testing part but now I am wondering for me to move it to production do I need to host the back end server for retrieving the tokens myself?
Currently I hosted the test server locally to test that it works. But what now? Do I need to host this on a server for all time so my app can get its tokens?
Please help.

Comment: Your backend server needs to be running on a URL accessible from wherever your app is running. So generally, yes, you need to host a server somewhere for this.

Comment: OK thank you. I read somewhere that AWS Lambda could be used and that way I don't need to manage any server...and the code just runs when its used. Have you heard of this option?

Comment: You can use Lambdas for it, although you may need to put an API Gateway in front of it so you can access it from your app safely

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to.
You can start with a Virtual Machine at DigitalOcean or Vultr. Replicate your test environment there, then harden the server, etc.
If you're new to that then I recommend you to find someone who has experience setting up servers in production environments.

Comment: OK thank you. I read somewhere that AWS Lambda could be used and that way I don't need to manage any server...and the code just runs when its used. Have you heard of this option?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. I spoke with Stripe and below was there response. They confirmed that you do need a server backend all the time.

--
Unfortunately, we don’t provide any hosted solutions when working with app based payment flows—you would need to have a back-end setup in place or use a serverless solution such as Heroku, both for your eventual move to a production environment and also while in development to test your back-end.

Generally speaking, you’ll use our SDKs when building your app to implement our client-side framework enabling you to securely collect and tokenize payment details from customers from within your app. However, the back-end server is where you’ll actually make requests to Stripe when you need to create a charge, refund a payment or take some other API related action.

Additionally, your back-end server will play a critical role as that’s where you’ll need to generate the ephemeral keys that will be used as the client-side session credentials for the app’s user.  The use of ephemeral keys will facilitate the retrieval and updating of customer objects in Stripe for a given user (the persistent creation and use of individual customer objects is a default behavior for our mobile SDKs), but will ensure that your Stripe account’s secret API keys remain protected (public API keys are still used in the client).